# Part pokemon am I

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, language

> Part pokemon am I,
>   or perhaps two,
>
> But not to belie,
>   what I think of you.
>
> I’m often confused,
>   with low ‘r camping
>
> Or expressly used,
>   when overbar adding.

What am I?

**Hint 1**

> In the line "with low ‘r camping", the 'r stands for or. I did the 'r to make it flow smoother and to make the distinction between the two less obvious. But they ARE separate. "with low or camping". This is the line that the language tag applies to.

**Hint 2**

> The first 4 lines are about the word, the "I'm often confused.." is to tell that the next 3 lines are mistaken words (homophones/mispellings) for it.

**Hint 3**

> First 2 lines refer to 2 pokemon. The next 2 can be taken separately. The last 2 lines can be taken separately as well.

**Hint 4 - updated**

> One of the answers below is almost there, they are just slightly missing the mark. If it's partially correct...then what must the other parts be?

Comment: Not sure if its necessary, bc it only applies to a small part, but I added the language tag

Comment: Perhaps the first stanza is referring to rot13(Mncqbf)?

Comment: @PiIsNot3 Nope.

Answer (score 9):

My explanations need work, but I think you are:

> µ

Part pokemon am I,
or perhaps two,

> [Mew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mew_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) and [Mew 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mewtwo)

But not to belie,
what I think of you.

> You're the [Cat's Meow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_meow)?  or you're Average (mean)?

I’m often confused,
with low ‘r camping

> The symbol looks like an "r" that's lower down with a (tent??) on top?

Or expressly used,
when overbar adding.

> When you add the overbar, µ is expressly a statistical average (x-bar)

Comment: Good guess, but not quite. Some things don't fit right, I'm not sure how the belie line would allude to your suggestion. I could see why you would think that for the pokemon line, but that would be whole, not part ^-^

Comment: You're getting close though, you have some of the pieces, you just gotta put them together right :]

Answer (score 6):

You are

> mean.

Part pokemon am I,

> **Me**g**an**ium

or perhaps two,

> **Me**t**an**g

But not to belie,

> not to hide what you *mean*

what I think of you.

> the opinion that someone is *mean*

I’m often confused,
with low ‘r camping

> *mean* can mean *dishonest*, synonymous with *low* and *base* (base camp)

Or expressly used,

> expressed to convey exactly what you *mean*

when overbar adding.

> an overline indicates a sample *mean*

Comment: aaahh! very close! You got 2 of the lines correct!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your hints, is it:

> Peach?

Part pokemon am I, or perhaps two,

> Pidgey/ Pidgeotto/ Pidgeot

But not to belie, what I think of you.

> ?

I’m often confused,

with low ‘r camping

> low: cheap (anagram), camping: pitch

Or expressly used,

> as in the insulting word b*tch?

when overbar adding.

> ?

Comment: This is not the answer, but thanks for attempting. The real answer will make everything fall into place nicely.

Comment: @ΩKr I didn't know you liked playing Pokemon Go!

Answer (score 0):

I am building on and using pieces of the excellent @arbitrahj answer.

Are you

> mewing?

Part pokemon am I, or perhaps two,

> Mew and Mew 2 are pokemons

But not to belie, what I think of you.

> "What does your cat really think of you?" is a well known question. Cat's mewing does not provide an answer to it. Especially if it is a "sphynx" cat :-)

I’m often confused, with low ‘r camping

> "low" could mean "a sound made by cattle; a moo". Could be phonetically confused with mewing.
>
>  "camping" could mean "moving" like in "going camping". Could also be phonetically confused with mewing

Or expressly used, when overbar adding

> mewing is pronounced as /ˈmyo͞oiNG/ - overbar is added to show proper pronunciation.

Comment: I don't think it really fits the low or camping part. This is not the pokemon, but keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to build off of other people's answers here and take a guess:

> Meowth

Part pokemon am I, or perhaps two,

> mew and mewtwo definitely fit the bill here, but you're only using 'me'. It is only a part of both these pokemon. So 'Me' is the first part of the name.

But not to belie, what I think of you.

> Someone mentioned the really common question "What does your cat think of you?". Meowth is a cat.

I’m often confused,

with low ‘r camping

> Here we're basically building the second part of the name. low is an anagram for owl, and an h looks like a stake used to put up a camping tent. This is only partly complete, so we have 'owlh'.

Or expressly used,

when overbar adding.

> I'm a bit thrown off here because I can't separate the two lines, when in your 3rd hint you mention that they can be taken separately. But adding the overbar onto the 'l' character will make a 't', so all in all we get 'owth'

In conclusion:

> 'me' + 'owth' = Meowth!

edit :

> I guess the 3rd hint also throws me off about the second 2 lines and how they are separate, but I'm pretty sure I got the correct answer in the end anyways.

Comment: Nice attempt, but this is not the answer. Some of your guess were very reaching, but everything will fit in nicely with the right word. I thought your idea about the overbar and I was really creative, but that's not it. Keep thinking!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll take another stab at it:

> Slowking

Part pokemon am I, or perhaps two,

> Here we have a pokemon that shares part of his name with others (slowpoke, slowbro). He also has a shellder attached to his head, which might be what the two is referencing.

But not to belie, what I think of you.

> This is the only line I'm having trouble fitting into this. I'll make a crazy pitch and say it has something to do with slowking being really intelligent due to the shellder injecting venom into him, so maybe this is like he's being condescending or something.

I’m often confused, with low ‘r camping

> Both words that sound a lot like parts of slowking's name.

Or expressly used, when overbar adding.

> Perhaps the overbar here is the shellder being 'added' to his head.

If i'm not correct, could you possibly add a hint saying whether the answer is a pokemon or not? I'm assuming based on the title and the first two lines, but if it isn't, then it might not be obvious enough.

Comment: Make sure to carefully read the hints, and perhaps the comments on other posts. Your idea with the 2 part pokemon is creative and I like it! But this is not the correct answer.